# Can´t type open brace or backslash in cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin

I have been using Cygwin without trouble on a separate computer, and I do not recall having any trouble typing certain symbols. I just starting using Cygwin on a computer with a Spanish keyboard, and noticed that when I type "{" or "\" nothing happens.

Is there some issue with Cygwin so that it would not recognize characters from a European keyboard? For reference, the version number is "2.7.0(0.306/5/3)."

Comment: are you using mintty as terminal ?

Comment: No, just regular old Cygwin.

Comment: Than is a problem of windows keyboard layout for CMD console, not cygwin issue.